# x++ cannot read registry entry

Tags: x++, registrykey

I have a problem reading a registry entry in x++.

I'm trying to find the install Directory of the HelpServer. I'm working with the client on the same computer of the AOS and help server.

The key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Setup\HelpServer`
and the property is `InstallDir`.

When I try to read the node, the system returns no handle:

```
winapi::regOpenKey(#HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Setup\HelpServer', #KEY_READ);)
```

If I try to read the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Dynamics\6.0\Setup` that has a property with the same name of the above, I can read the value without any problem.